# Existence and uniqueness of MLE

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution, profile-likelihood

I am aiming to show that the MLE of $(\alpha, \lambda)$ for $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim \Gamma(\alpha,\lambda)$ exists and is unique, under the assumption that the $X_i$ are all positive and unequal. I am doing this through profiling, that is I found the profile likelihood of $\alpha$ to be:

$$F(\alpha) = n\alpha\log\left (\frac{\alpha}{\bar{X}} \right ) + (\alpha -1) \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(X_i) - n\alpha -n\log(\Gamma(\alpha))$$

and now I am differentiating with respect to $\alpha$ to show that there is a maximizing $\alpha$ for $F$. Differentiating $F$ and doing some algebra has gotten me to:

$$ \displaystyle \frac{d}{d\alpha} F(\alpha) = n\log\left (\frac{\alpha}{\bar{X}} \right ) +  \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(X_i) -n\frac{d}{d\alpha}\log(\Gamma(\alpha))$$

and the last term in the expression is the digamma function. It is hard to see how I should proceed from here. I need to show first that the derivative becomes $0$ (which seems like the hardest task). If it becomes zero at multiple points, I need to show that the maximizing point is unique. This process will probably require me to take the second derivative of $F$ and check concavity but I first need to establish that the first derivative becomes $0$. Any help on that front will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation, the MLE for the Gamma distribution does not exist in closed form for both parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Consider your function

$$F(\alpha) = n\alpha\log\left (\frac{\alpha}{\bar{X}} \right ) + (\alpha -1) \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(X_i) - n\alpha -n\log(\Gamma(\alpha))$$

[Convex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_analysis) tells us that if it is strictly concave, it has a single, unique, maximum.

- The function $n\alpha\log\left (\frac{\alpha}{\bar{X}} \right )$ is strictly concave (for $\alpha > 0$) - it is easy to differentiate it twice and verify that.
- The function $(\alpha -1) \sum_{i=1}^{n}\log(X_i)$ is [affine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).
- The [Bohr–Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) implies that the gamma function is log-convex; the negation of its log is therefore concave.

The sum of a strictly concave, affine, and concave function, is strictly concave. It has a unique, single, maximum.